# How to get the app permission for UWP App developed under App settings

Tags: uwp, appx, msix

I am developing an UWP Appx Package, where I added the capabilities(say webcam) in the manifest file. But I am not able to see the webcam capability under app setting permission.
PLease let me know what I need to do get the capability under the app settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are expecting is a Windows 8 Store app experience, that the user can find the permission toggles by opening Charm Bar and then selecting Settings->Permissions.

On UWP, there is no Charm Bar. You are expected to provide a convenient link to [launch the Settings app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app) to a specific page for the permission the app is requesting.

Use the **ms-settings** scheme in the link.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:privacy-webcam"));
```

You can put the convenient link in the Settings panel of the app.